# Jquery : UI effects for specific browsers

Tags: jquery

I have a Jquery Dialog box and the code is below,

```
$(document).ready(function()
            {
            $("#dialogForm").dialog({
         autoOpen:true,
     position:'center',
        height:187,
        width: 472,
        modal: true,
show: {effect: 'explode', duration: 350}

            });
$('#body').show();
            });
```

Here am using `effect` which is `explode` and duration is 350. This works perfect in Chrome and FF browsers. But in IE though it works am not getting the `explode` effect which am getting in Chrome/FF. Dialog box appears but, it appears like with no effects. Since the duration is 350 here, and since effect is not visible in IE, it appears that it is taking time for the Dialog box to get rendered.

So, am not caring for this effect for IE users but instead want to retain for Chrome/FF users. Is there any way I can say that for IE -no effect and for Chrome/ FF apply this effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
if ( !($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 7.0) ){
```

...
}

More info: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/